# libiomp5.so (with ompt support) cannot trigger ompt_intialize() in an offload openmp environment

Tags: openmp, intel-mic

I'm running an Intel MIC offload openmp application using openmp runtime (with ompt support, both the CPU side and the MIC side), while libiomp5.so on the CPU side can trigger its ompt_intialize() and get profile data, libiomp5.so on the MIC side cannot trigger its ompt_intialize(), so that I cannot get the profile data I want. I'm wondering where the problem is.

Comment: which compiler version are you using? Does it already have ompt support? Ompt is not widely availanle at the moment, did you compile the llvm's runtime yourself?

Comment: I'm sorry. I just leave out too many details.

 I'm using TAU(Tuning and Analysis Utilities) to instrument MIC offload application with openmp code. TAU is configured with ompt option, and the ompt mentioned above is from TAU release.

Comment: Maybe your best approach would be to contact the TAU people. Here you can find this the contact information: https://www.cs.uoregon.edu/research/tau/contact.php

Answer (score 0):

In order use TAU on both the host and the device, you have to configure and build TAU twice - once for the x86_64 architecture, and once for mic_linux.  I assume you already did that?

My assumption is that the libiomp5.so library included with TAU was only compiled for the host, and is not binary compatible with the device (so the one included with the Intel compiler is used instead).  I suspect that if you performed the second configure/build step for the device, that process detected the libiomp5.so library in the TAU library directory, and didn't rebuild it for the device - but I don't know that for sure.

We recently updated the OMPT support in TAU, and released v2.25 in mid-November. If you continue to have problems, please contact tau-bugs@cs.uoregon.edu.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I think I have done everything right. The libiomp5.so for the device and host both exist, and they are different. I'm now using an old version of v2.23. Maybe I should use v2.25 instead.